# how to convert .py made with kivy to .exe

Tags: python, kivy, cx-freeze

I have made a GUI application with python GUI Kivy. I have first used pyinstaller to convert my code to exe but it gave an error no module named kivy. now i am using cx_Freeze but I still get an error when i run the exe.
Error:

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc4, git-d74461b, 20201015
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "E:\python*********\buil*\exe.win-amd64-3.8\lib\kivy\__init__.pyc"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 17:30:36) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "E:\pytho**\bui***\exe.win-amd64-3.8\jarv.exe"
[ERROR  ] [Clock       ] Unable to import kivy._clock. Have you perhaps forgotten to compile kivy? Kivy contains Cython code which needs to be compiled. A missing kivy._clock often indicates the Cython code has not been compiled. Please follow the installation instructions and make sure to compile Kivy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eth**\ad********\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 41, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\ase\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 36, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "jarv.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\ase\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\boxlayout.py", line 77, in <module>
    from kivy.uix.layout import Layout
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\ase\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 58, in <module>
    from kivy.clock import Clock
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\ase3\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 466, in <module>
    from kivy._clock import CyClockBase, ClockEvent, FreeClockEvent, \
  File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 10, in init kivy._clock
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.weakmethod'
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally pyinstaller works fine for me.
When it doesn't work I just upgrade it with
`pip install --upgrade pyinstaller` and then try again.
Also make sure your script is not named `Kivy.py` or `kivy.py`.
If your script is named `kivy.py`,the script keeps importing itself and may throw an error.